# Python ctypes access violation when accessing an .exe exported function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, access-violation

I'm getting an access violation, when calling an exported c++ function through ctypes on python.

I narrowed the problem down to the following c++ function: (compiled on vs2017)

```
#include <cstdio>
__declspec(dllexport) void x()
{
    FILE* out = stdout; // After debugging, this is where the access violation happens.
}
```

When calling the function I get the following error (same error that shows when debugging with vs):

Python code:

```
ctypes.windll.<exe_name>.x()
```

Error:

> OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x_some_address

The key factor is, the above was compiled as an EXE.

(The whole thing started when I exported a function that calls the 'main' entry point)

After spending some time on this and trying everything, I tried compiling the above as a DLL, and now it's working as expected.

So the question is, can someone explain to me what was causing the problem?

I'm aware (more or less) of the memory management differences, but not the details.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you tried to call an `.exe` using `ctypes`?  Please show your Python code the the error occurred.  Please also show the exporting of the function, and the function code, that calls `main`.

Comment: Added py code.

Exporting of the function is shown. This is vs, so dllexport is what adds it to the vtable.
Function that calls main is irrelevant. I presented the problem is a concise manner and all needed information to reproduce the results are here. I only mentioned it for some background.

Comment: `dllexport` has nothing to do with the vtable.  The vtable is a C++ specific device used to support virtual functions, it is used by other implementations than VS.  `dllexport` stores function names in the DLL's export table, is Windows specific, and is also used in C programs.  In the DLL, did you have a `DllMain()` function?

Comment: You're right. I meant the export table, of course. I did not have a DllMain. Since it was linked to the CRT, I guess it has the CRTs entry point. Maybe that explains something.

Comment: "all needed information to reproduce the results are here".  Nope.  That function doesn't compile...as an EXE or DLL.

Comment: Your right. I didn't think about compatibility with other platforms and configurations. Modified. Try now please. (If not working, please include error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article seems to give enough background information and a possible solution for this matter:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/Load-EXE-as-DLL-Mission-Possible

The main differences are of loading an EXE as a DLL are:

> - The CRT is not initialized, including any global variables, and
> - The Import Address Table is not correctly configured, which means that all calls to imported functions will crash.

Comment: In other words, build it as a DLL :^)

Comment: The question already s points that out. I knew what the solution was, but I was asking for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: I saw that, I was just commenting on the complexity of making it work.